# VBA Excel copy multiple shapes to clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with four shapes and a couple of buttons to run macros. The shapes are named topCircle, leftCircle, rightCircle & midCircle.

Wanting one of the buttons to run a macro that copies the four shapes to clipboard, for pasting into other Office docs.

Have been though various MSDN articles (like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff940375.aspx) but having trouble. Trying to imitate the example on the linked article, I wrote this:

```
Set myDocument = Worksheets("Overall")

myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("leftCircle", "rightCircle", "topCircle", "midCircle")).Copy
```

But getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method". Have also tried a few other things without luck. Any ideas as to how to get this to work? Cheers!

Comment: Even though I don't like to use `Select`, if you change to `myDocument.Shapes.range(Array("leftCircle", "rightCircle", "topCircle", "midCircle")).Select` and after add `Selection.Copy` it will work. Let me "play" a little more to avoid this "ugly" work-around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that to copy multiple shapes from an Excel worksheet you have 3 options:

**Option 1**: Use `Select` first to select all `Shapes`, and then copy the `Selection` :

```
myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("leftCircle", "rightCircle", "topCircle", "midCircle")).Select
Selection.Copy
```

**Option 2**: Use the `Group` to group all selected shapes, then copy them together, and afterwards use the `Ungroup` to split them back:

```
With myDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("leftCircle", "rightCircle", "topCircle", "midCircle"))
    .Group.Copy
    ' paste to wherever you want

    .Ungroup
End With
```

**Option 3**: use `For Each MyShape In myDocument.Shapes` to loop through all `Shapes` in `myDocument` worksheet, and if it mathces one of the `Shape.Name` you wanted it, copy it:

```
Dim MyShape     As Shape

For Each MyShape In myDocument.Shapes
    Select Case MyShape.Name
        Case "leftCircle", "rightCircle", "topCircle", "midCircle"
            MyShape.Copy
            ' paste to wherever you want

    End Select
Next MyShape
```